# Google play services: BAD_AUTHENTICATION

Tags: android, google-play-services

I run my app on google nexus 10 inch device, whenever app is launch i got this issue,app is not crashing but got this. here is stactrace

```
02-15 16:36:53.417 4047-16948/? E/ctxmgr: [SyncServerInterestRecordsOperation]Failed WriteInterestRecord: network status=-1
02-15 16:37:28.655 4047-14343/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:1546944079>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller
                                        fck: Long live credential not available.
                                            at fcl.b(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:10)
                                            at fcl.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:50)
                                            at fav.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:37)
                                            at got.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:7)
                                            at got.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:155)
                                            at gnt.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:2)
                                            at gnr.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:17)
                                            at gnr.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:6)
                                            at cpa.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:25)
                                            at cpa.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:80)
                                            at exy.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:6)
                                            at exx.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:2)
                                            at exx.e(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:6)
                                            at exx.d(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:1)
                                            at exv.b(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:1)
                                            at mra.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:1)
                                            at mpn.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:3)
                                            at dgn.a(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:54)
                                            at dbw.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:2)
                                            at dbu.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:3)
                                            at mvq.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:6)
                                            at mwc.run(:com.google.android.gms@11951230:26)
```

can someone tell me about this. any help will be appreciate. Thanks!!

Comment: what happens if you reboot phone, clean project and rebuild?

Comment: @noogui i did it, nothing happen.

Comment: @HemantParmar Have you update device google play services ? which os in nexus 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are running your app with a proxy. Try doing the same on a open network and check if the error is still showing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `E/ctxmgr: [SyncServerInterestRecordsOperation]Failed WriteInterestRecord: network status=-1` in the stack-trace, could you run a check on the following 2 things:
1. Network connectivity between the application and the play-store.
2. Try clearing the app cache and try again.

Hope this helps

Comment: i done silly mistake with network changes, thanks for your solution.